# S3 LTE keeps rebooting

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I bet this problem has been posted many times but my galaxy S3 keeps rebooting the samsung logo over and over again. I've tried entering recovery mode but just when I'm about to select an option it reboots again...I thought it could be the power button so I opened up the phone to see if it's not being pressed down but it looked fine, I even removed the button to make sure(using a toothpick as a replacement button hehe).

So where could the problem be?!

Comment: If it's not an empty battery, it's most likely a case for the service. Did you do anything specific before this issue came up? From what you wrote, it's hard to see what could be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put any custom rom's on your phone?

Could be a bad one which is causing this

Either way your best option is to download stock rom for your device and flash it over via Odin

Comment: Nope haven't done anything to it really..it just started acting that way all suddenly yesterday...
never flashed a smarthphone..could you provide me a good step by step guide?

Comment: Hi try putting your phone into download mode, using power, home button and down volume all at once, if that work ill provide you with a guide tomorrow morning

Comment: Any luck @MizziPizzi